# Creating table in ArcToolbox Script with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, table

I want to create a Python Script for ArcGIS, using `arcpy`.
The script would have several user input fields. I would like to create a table based on one or two of the user input (the `path` and `name`).
I am trying :

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.management import CreateFeatureclass
workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
poly = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
poly_nou = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
input_areas = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
direction = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)


env.workspace = workspace
out_path = os.path.split(poly_nou)[0]
name =  os.path.split(poly_nou)[1]

arcpy.CreateTable(out_path, name)
```

I have set up the Script in ArcMap to look like this:
1. Workspace type
2. Feature class
3. Table
4 and 5 Strings

I want the script to read 3 (possibly also 1) and create a table.

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Proiecte\Python Toolbox\Divide_percentage.py", line 16, in 
>       arcpy.CreateTable(out_path, name)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateTable' Failed to execute (Script1).

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to run a geoprocessing tool using Python.

1. To use its corresponding function.

   ```
   arcpy.<toolname_toolboxalias>(parameters)
   ```
2. To  call the toolbox as a module and then the tool as a function.
   Geoprocessing tools are also available in modules that match the toolbox alias name. The syntax is as follows:

   ```
   arcpy.<toolboxalias>.<toolname>(parameters)
   ```

Since `CreateTable` table is in `management` toolbox, you should use one of the following lines:

```
arcpy.CreateTable_management(out_path, name)

# OR
arcpy.management.CreateTable(out_path, name)
```

Answer (score 3):

A classic case of time to read the help file! If you go to the [Create Table tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-table.htm), in fact any geoprocessing tools' help page, you see a syntax section and a code example of how to use the tool in python. Have a look at that then your line of code that creates the table, what is missing...?